# How can I store a token in the browser using Flask, Basic Auth with Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, flask-login

Just a heads up, I am new to how most of this works, so sorry in advance if it is a simple subject.

I am trying to setup a simple RESTful site using basic auth for logins with Flask. I have a page (admin_panel) that requires me to login and a login page (login). If I go to the admin_panel, the browser make a pop up which allows me to enter my username and password. Once verified I believe it stores a token so that when I go to other pages I don't need to login again. This all works.

On the login page, I didn't want to have the pop up, so I added ajax to do the POST with the Authentication Headers. This works and successfully logs me in.

Once I login with the login page and then go to the admin_panel page, the browser pops up another login box. I believe this is because I did not store the token when doing the ajax POST.

How can I store the token in a similar manor to the pop up but all through ajax?

Here is the login_auth javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind the form submit event to our function
    $("#loginForm").bind('submit', function(e) {
        // prevent page refresh
        e.preventDefault();
        // post the data
        var username = $(this).find('input[name="username"]').val();
        var password = $(this).find('input[name="password"]').val();
        var ajax=$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true,
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
            },
            data: { },
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log('Login Success!')
            location.reload();
        });
        ajax.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('error! '+jqXHR+' - '+textStatus+' - '+errorThrown);
        });
    });
});
```

Here are the Flask pages:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from flask import Flask, abort, request, jsonify, g, url_for, render_template
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
from itsdangerous import (TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer
                          as Serializer, BadSignature, SignatureExpired)
from functools import wraps

# initialization
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super duper easy secret key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///mydb.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True

# extensions
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_role = db.Column(db.Enum('admin', 'user', name='user_role'))

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password_hash)

    def generate_auth_token(self, expiration=600):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=expiration)
        return s.dumps({'id': self.id})

    @staticmethod
    def verify_auth_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except SignatureExpired:
            return None    # valid token, but expired
        except BadSignature:
            return None    # invalid token
        user = User.query.get(data['id'])
        return user
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    # first try to authenticate by token
    user = User.verify_auth_token(username_or_token)
    if not user:
        # try to authenticate with username/password
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username_or_token).first()
        if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
            return False
    g.user = user
    return True

def verify_role(role):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            if g.user.user_role == role:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                abort(400) # incorrect role
        return decorated
    return decorator

@app.route('/api/users/<int:id>')
def get_user(id):
    user = User.query.get(id)
    if not user:
        abort(400)
    return jsonify({'username': user.username})


@app.route('/api/token')
@auth.login_required
def get_auth_token():
    token = g.user.generate_auth_token(600)
    return jsonify({'token': token.decode('ascii'), 'duration': 600})

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    print request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'posted', request.form.get('username'), request.form.get('password')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def _login():
   # HTTP Auth should do its thing
   return jsonify({"login": "success", "user": g.user.username})

@app.route('/admin/')
@auth.login_required
@verify_role('admin')
def admin_panel():
    return jsonify({'data': 'Hello, %s!' % g.user.username})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists('mydb.db'):
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm not even sure this is the way I should be doing this. Also this is currently being used locally but if it moves elsewhere I would end up using ssl.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you not log the successful login response data to the console, pick out the token and store it locally with localStorage.setItem('the_token') and access as needed?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I could do that. I'd still be interested in knowing where the browser is storing it. Or if not the browser whats going on behind the scenes with HttpBasicAuth.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the browser just caches the username and password and reuses them without needing to  request it again from the user. Is that what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Basic Auth, the browser does **not** store a separate token. In Basic Auth, the username and password is sent with every single request. Your browser just does so automatically for you.

This is also why your authentication scheme doesn't work: The browser is unaware of your previous request and does not store the credentials. Therefore it asks you when it receives the next authentication challenge from the server. There is no way for you to change this as major browsers don't expose an API to store random credentials for security reasons.

The only way around this is to not rely on Basic Auth but to spin your own authentication mechanism.